# In VBA Find a Cell on a Specified Excel Worksheet without Activating the Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to locate a cell with formula "CAL JUMP INTENS" on a worksheet "this worksheet". The following code works.

```
worksheets("this worksheet").activate
Set target = Cells.Find(What:="CAL JUMP INTENS", After:=ActiveCell, _ LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
```

However, I would not like to activate the worksheet "this worksheet". Is there a way to do this? I would need to locate this cell restricted to this worksheet "this worksheet" rather than the whole workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qualify the `Find()` method with a range and a sheet object:

```
Set target = Sheets("this worksheet").Cells.Find(What:="CAL JUMP INTENS", After:=ActiveCell, _ LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
```

It's *extremely* rare in VBA that you ever have to `Activate` or `Select` anything.

Comment: I just tried putting the worksheet name in front of "cells" before seeing your answer and it worked. Thank you all the same. Your last statement is very useful. I will remember that.

Comment: Not a problem, things like `Ranges` or `Worksheets` in VBA are all objects, and you can access their properties and methods directly by using dot notation (placing a `.` after it). VBA also has something called IntelliSense - so when you type a `.` after something you will see a dropdown menu with all it's properties and methods. Handy if you want to learn :)

Comment: That last sentence is extremely important and a seemingly universal problem with people learning VBA. I'm not sure if that is because of how the tutorials are written or what. Activating and Selecting are unreliable, inefficient, and lead to unexpected bugs. I only use them to set selection at the very end for the user. I never pull data based on Selection.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Could even go a step further and use `Application.Goto()` instead of selecting something :)

Comment: Could you please give an example of using Application.Goto()?

Comment: @Hans Let me just point out that you need to replace `ActiveCell` as well which you supplied in the `After` argument. You have to be explicit about it as well. If you omit the `Activate` method of the worksheet object (which is desirable), your `ActiveCell` will still be the cell within your currently active worksheet. And that might cause you issues.

Comment: @L42: Do you mean to put, say, "After:=Worksheets("this worksheet").Range("A1")"?

Comment: @Hans MSDN article on `Application.Goto` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839232.aspx

Comment: @Hans Yes that is what L42 means assuming you are searching from the top left of the worksheet.

Comment: @Hans Yes. But you can also omit it as what is discussed [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx). If you do that, `the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range`.

Comment: @L42: I just edited the answer of S O to reflect your comment on "After:".

Comment: Absolutely. Though to be honest I am not sure whether `Application.Goto` is any better than `Range(...).Select`. It may be. I just don't know.

Comment: @Hans Cool, also posted an answer for just additional info. I can't fit it to comments.

Answer (score 1):

Although SO provided an answer to your question, this serves just an additional info.
Do not pick it as answer. :)

1. Use With Clause

   ```
   With Worksheets("SheetName")
       .Cells.Find(What:="CAL JUMP INTENS", _
                   After:=.Range("A1"), _ ' notice that this is referenced to your sheet
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=True, _
                   SearchFormat:=False)
   End With
   ```
2. Know the default values
   If you know the default values of arguments and that is what you need, then might as well not be explicit about it. Above arguments you included are all default values (except, `LookAt`)so might as well omit them? When I say *Default*, it is the Excel settings when you start it anew (first time).

   ```
   With Worksheets("SheetName")
       .Cells.Find(What:="CAL JUMP INTENS", _
                   After:=.Range("A1"), _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole)
   End With
   ```

   Or in your case, you really need not supply the `After` argument (since you are searching the entire worksheet). So,

   ```
   Worksheets("SheetName").Cells.Find("CAL JUMP INTENS", , , xlWhole)
   ```

   will work just fine.

**Important:**
As what SO noted, the default properties of find method for `LookIn`, `LookAt` and `SearchOrder` are the last used settings for it as what is pointed out in [HERE](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm).

> "It is very important to understand that the settings LookIn, LookAt and SearchOrder are saved each time the Find Method is used. For this reason one should always specify these settings explicitly each and every time you use the Find Method. If you don't, you run the risk of using the Find Method with settings you were not aware of."

Comment: Is "LookAt:=xlWhole" also default?

Comment: @Hans Nope. I missed that on the first post. :)

Comment: The properties for the `Find()` method default to whatever was used the last time, even through using Ctrl + F

Comment: @SO True. What I'm referring to as default is when you start Excel anew. Hans, this is worth noting as well and very important. I will add it on the post.